# How to use SPEL eval @environment.getProperty(String string, Class<T> targetType) in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-el

How to use SPEL eval

```
@environment.getProperty(String string, Class<T> targetType)
```

in JSP?

I have a .property file with following entry,

```
app.conf.context.is_this_ok=true
```

I was able to get this working in JSP, with string valued varibale.

```
    <spring:eval var="isThisOk"
 expression="@environment.getProperty('app.conf.context.is_this_ok')"/>
```

But failed with getting value as boolean with following,

```
    <spring:eval var="isThisOk" expression="
           @environment.getProperty('app.conf.context.is_this_ok', 
                <%= java.lang.Boolean.class %>)"
    />
```

Please do suggest a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<spring:eval var="isThisOk" expression="
    @environment.getProperty('app.conf.context.is_this_ok', T(java.lang.Boolean))"
/>
```

This is [Spring EL syntax](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) for accessing types.